# asking user to enter the text file name

Tags: python, nltk

i have this python code which make stemming for lists of words form text file and save the results to another text file ,but I want to adjust the code by the following :

1. aske the user to enter the full path of the input(words text file)
2. save the output(original words + stemmed words) in full path text file that the user enter it

   ```
   import nltk
   from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
   from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer
   from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
   stemmer = PorterStemmer()
   with open(r'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Final Project\now.txt', 'r') as fp:
   tokens = fp.readlines()
   for t in tokens:
    s = stemmer.stem(t.strip())
    print(s, file=open("output.txt", "a"))
   ```

any help?

Comment: Just replace the two filenames with `input()`.

Comment: Indentation and spacing matter in Python, unlike other languages. The convention is 4 spaces per level of indent (not 1). You have to indent the body of the `with ...` clause, otherwise the `fp` object it declares isn't visible to the code so it does't work.

Comment: Thank you, I already know that, but while I posted the question I made more spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

stemmer = PorterStemmer()

input_path = input("Please type the path of the input file: ")
output_path = input("Please type the path of the output file: ")

with open(input_path, 'r') as fp:
    tokens = fp.readlines()

for t in tokens:
    s = stemmer.stem(t.strip())
    print(f"{t.strip()} {s}", file=open(output_path, "a"))
```

Explanation:

- the [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function prints a prompt (the strings it receives as parameters) and waits for an input, which it returns.
- the [`with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) statement is used for context management and will lead to the open file being automatically closed when we exit the context. The code to be executed within this context must be indented. You can read more [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html).
- the `for` loop requires that the code being looped is indented.
- to elegantly show the words and their stems one after another, [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) were used. The `.strip()` function removes whitespace - this means it will remove any spaces or newlines in the given strings.
- finally, most of the imports were not needed for the code to run, so they were removed.